# Non-triviality of Morrey spaces

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

As is well known,  Morrey  spaces are widely used   to
investigate the local behavior of solutions to second order elliptic partial differential
equations. Recall that the classical Morrey spaces $\mathcal{M}^{p,\lambda}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ are defined by
\begin{equation*} 
\mathcal{M}^{p,\lambda}(\mathbb{R}^{n}) = \left\{ f \in L^p_{\rm loc}(\mathbb{R}^{n}) : \left\| f\right\|_{\mathcal{M}^{p,\lambda}}:
= \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}, \; r>0 } r^{-\frac{\lambda}{p}} \|f\|_{L^p (B(x,r))} < \infty \right\},
\end{equation*}
where $0 \le \lambda \le  n,$ $1\le p < \infty$. Note that $\mathcal{M}^{p,0}(\mathbb{R}^{n})=L^{p}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ and $\mathcal{M}^{p,n}(\mathbb{R}^{n})=L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$.
If $\lambda<0$ or $\lambda>n$, then $\mathcal{M}^{p,\lambda }(\mathbb{R}^{n})={\Theta}$,
where $\Theta$ is the set of all functions equivalent to $0$ on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Indeed, first let $\lambda<0$ and $f\in \mathcal{M}^{p,\lambda}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$,
then we have for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $r>0$
\begin{align*}
\|f\|_{L^{p}(B(x,r))}\le r^{\frac{\lambda}{p}}\| f\|_{\mathcal{M}^{p,\lambda }}.
\end{align*}
Consequently we get
$$
\|f\|_{L^{p}(\mathbb{R}^{n})}=\lim_{r\rightarrow \infty}\|f\|_{L^{p}(B(x,r))}=0\Rightarrow f(x)=0, \text{   for a.e. }x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}.
$$
Now let $\lambda>n$ and $f\in \mathcal{M}^{p,\lambda}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$. Then, we have for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $r>0$
\begin{align}\tag{*}
\frac{\|f\chi_{B(x,r)}\|_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^{n})}}{\|\chi_{B(x,r)}\|_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^{n})}}\le v_n^{-\frac{1}{p}} r^{\frac{\lambda-n}{p}}\| f\|_{\mathcal{M}^{p,\lambda }},
\end{align}
where $v_n$ is the volume of the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

By the Lebesgue theorem
on differentiation of integrals we know that for all $f\in  L^p_{\rm loc}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$
\begin{align}
\lim_{r\rightarrow 0} \frac{\|f\chi_{B(x,r)}\|_{L_p(\mathbb{R}^{n})}}{\|\chi_{B(x,r)}\|_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^{n})}}=|f(x)| \text{   for a.e. }x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}.
\end{align}
Using this fact in (*) we get  $f(x)=0$ for a.e. $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

By $W\mathcal{M}^{p,\lambda}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ we denote the
weak Morrey space defined as the set of
functions $f\in WL^{p}_{\rm loc}(\mathbb{R}^{n}) $ for which
$$
\left\| f\right\|_{W\mathcal{M}^{p,\lambda }} := \sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}^{n}, \; r>0} r^{-\frac{\lambda}{p}}
\|f\|_{WL^{p}(B(x,r))} <\infty,
$$
where $WL^{p}(B(x,r))$ denotes the weak $L^p$-space of measurable functions
$f$ for which
\begin{align*}
\begin{split}
\|f\|_{WL^{p}(B(x,r))} & \equiv \|f \chi_{_{B(x,r)}}\|_{WL^{p}(\mathbb{R}^{n})} 
\\
&= \sup_{t>0}t \left|\left\{y\in B(x,r) : \,|f(y)| > t \right\}
\right|^{1/{p}} %\label{ISAAC2}
\\
&=\sup_{0<t\le |B(x,r)|} t^{1/{p}} \left( f \chi_{_{B(x,r)}}  \right)^{*}(t) <\infty.
\end{split}
\end{align*}
Here $g^{*}$ denotes the non-increasing rearrangement of the function $g$.

For the non-triviality of weak Morrey space where should $\lambda$ be? I think it is obvious that if $\lambda=0$ then $W\mathcal{M}^{p,0}(\mathbb{R}^{n})=WL^{p} (\mathbb{R}^{n})$ and if $\lambda<0$ then $W\mathcal{M}^{p,\lambda }(\mathbb{R}^{n})={\Theta}$. Also, for my opinion if $\lambda=n$ then
\begin{align*}
\begin{split}
r^{-\frac{n}{p}}
\|f\|_{WL^{p}(B(x,r))}&=r^{-\frac{n}{p}} \sup_{0<t\le |B(x,r)|} t^{1/{p}} \left( f \chi_{_{B(x,r)}}  \right)^{*}(t)\\
&\leq v_{n}^{\frac{1}{p}}\left( f \chi_{_{B(x,r)}}  \right)^{*}(0)\\
&\leq v_{n}^{\frac{1}{p}}\|f\|_{L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^{n})}.
\end{split}
\end{align*}
So $L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^{n})\hookrightarrow W\mathcal{M}^{p,n}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$.

What do you think about the embedding $W\mathcal{M}^{p,n}(\mathbb{R}^{n})\hookrightarrow L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ ? Is it true? Also what do you think about the other cases of $\lambda$ ? For which cases of $\lambda$ the weak Morrey spaces are trivial?